# VueJS component rerenders when props is unchanged

Tags: vue.js, memoization

I have a list in the vuex store with tables[t1,t2], when t1 updates i have to mutate the tables array in order to have the t1 updates.

For each table i use a `<Table v-for="(item, index) in tables" :key="index" :data="item">` where it uses a Table.vue. In Table.Vue i have:

```
 props: {
   data: {
     type: Object,
     default: null
   }
 },
```

But when t1 changes it also forces an update to t2, which is understandable because the whole "tables" variable in store gets mutated. But I only want the component to update when there is an actual change in props, so that the t2 doesn't get updated unnecessarily. I've tried to look into memoization, which i used previously in React-projects to fix this problem. I didn't really find anything easy to use and searching "memoization vuejs" didn't really give me alot to go on.

What i do in the mutation in vuex store in order to mutate a table:

```
 my_mutation(state, data) {
    let newList = [...state.tables];
    let index = newList.findIndex(i => i.tableName === data.tableName);
    if (index !== -1) {
       newList[index] = data.value;
    } 
    Vue.set(state, 'currentViews', newList);
}
```

as you can see this code only mutate 1 element at the time in the state.tables, but sets the whole tables variable. This causes the update() function to trigger in the components (notice not created() as this only happens initally when i fetch and populate the tables variable) and rerenders the component.

Since the created() is not triggered when the mutation happens, this tells me that the component is still there and doesn't need to be recreated. The goal here is not to trigger updated() when theres no changes to the props and prevent rerendering of that particular component.

Comment: when you use `:key` vue by itself check it for you and render only the part which got changed. just use some id and not index.

Comment: That's how Vue works. Why is this even problem ? Whats your concern?

Comment: @MichalLevý theres no need for the component to update when theres no changes? Anyways, all off the Table.vue components get repopulated creating alot of unwanted movement

Comment: btw is your `Table` component functional ?

Comment: @MichalLevý No, just using regular component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have another component inside Table.vue which was dependent on a store variable which was mutated when changing t1 causing the rest of the tables to change. Tip of the day: check if all the nested component isnt dependent on some store variable effected by the change

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add some code because what you say you see seems strange...

Look at the following example (updated example to use Vuex...just to be sure)

- first button mutate the 1st table's data at index 0. **Result** = only 1st component re-renders
- second button completely replaces data for 2nd table. **Result** = only 2nd component re-renders
- 3rd button replaces whole `tables` array by a new array. **Result** = both component's re-render (as expected)
- 4th button for curious people ;) ...completely new `tables` array composed from existing instances. **Result** = no re-render at all
- 5th button (added after Q update)

  - same way of updating as in question
  - **Result** - only 2nd table rerenders! Clear contradiction to what you say...
  - note that if you have `currentViews` property in the `state` from the beggining, you don't need to use `Vue.set` - simple assignment will suffice

**Update**: Added `updated` hook with `console.log` into `mytable` component to check if logs correlate with time changes in tables headers - confirmed

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    tables: [
        ['item 1', 'item 2'],
        ['item 1', 'item 2']
      ]
  },
  mutations: {
    mutate1st(state) {
      Vue.set(state.tables[0], 0, state.tables[0][0]+'+1')
    },
    mutateTables(state) {
      Vue.set(state.tables, 1, ['item 3', 'item 4'])
    },
    replaceTables(state) {
      state.tables = [
        ['item 1', 'item 2'],
        ['item 1', 'item 2']
      ]
    },
    newArrayCreatedFromPreviousOnes(state) {
      state.tables = [...state.tables]  // we are creating new array composed from existing instances
    },
    sameWayAsInQuestion(state) {
      let newList = [...state.tables];
      newList[1] = ['item 5', 'item 6'];
      Vue.set(state, 'tables', newList);
    } 
  }
})

const mytable = Vue.component('mytable', {
  props: ['title', 'data'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div> {{ title }} ({{ now() }}) </div>
      <div v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">{{ item }}</div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    now() {
      const date = new Date();
      return date.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
  },
  updated() {
    console.log(`${this.title} updated at ${this.now()}`)
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  store,
  components: { mytable },
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="mutate1st">Mutate 1st table data</button>
      <button @click="mutateTables">Mutate tables array</button>
      <button @click="replaceTables">Replace tables array</button>
      <button @click="newArrayCreatedFromPreviousOnes">Just for curiosity...</button>
      <button @click="sameWayAsInQuestion">Same way as in question</button>
      <hr>
      <mytable v-for="(table, index) in $store.state.tables" :key="index" :title="'Table ' + index" :data="table" />
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(['mutate1st', 'mutateTables', 'replaceTables', 'newArrayCreatedFromPreviousOnes', 'sameWayAsInQuestion'])  
  }
})

app.$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: In the vuex store i basiclly do what you have done in the NewArrayCreatedFromPreviousOnes(), but I do changes to the first array as well. I have created() and updated() in the Table.vue to see wether the compnents rerender or gets recreated when t1 gets modified. And initally every table gets created, and then when i update  t1 both triggers update(). I'll update my question with some code.

Comment: Added one more button with the same "update" logic as in your question. I'm still not able to reproduce your results...

Comment: Ahh, I found the problem. I have another component inside Table.vue which was dependent on a store variable which was mutated when changing t1 causing the rest of the tables to change. This dependency wasn't suppose to be there.Thanks for scoping down my problem!